# Python Pandas IDE that would "know" columns and types

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, ide

I'm doing some development in Python, mostly using a simple text editor (Sublime Text). I'm mostly dealing in databases that I fit in Pandas DataFrames. My issue is, I often lose track of the column names, and occasionally the column types as well. Is there some IDE / plug-in / debug tool that would allow me to look into each DataFrame and see how it's defined, a little bit like Eclipse can do for Java classes?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/), at least that's the one that I currently use. Not sure if other ones have the same capabilities.

It has matlab like features that allows you to view your variables and a great tool for numpy arrays and pandas dataframes.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

foo = 7
arr = np.array([0,5,9])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr).T
df.columns = ['spam','eggs','bar']
```

In the Variable Explorer you'll see the following:

[image]

Here's a view of the dataframe (double click). Can also be done to arrays:

[image]

*Note:* For numpy arrays you can change from showing max/min to truncated values, to full array.

Comment: Looks exactly like what I was looking for, will take a look, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that something like that exists, but you can always use `df.info()`.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is what I'm using now (and df.columns), it's great for scripting but not as useful for developing...